# indexedDb не отрабатывает onsuccess

Tags: indexeddb

есть некий класс IndexedDb

```js
   
class IndexedDb {

    constructor() {
        var self = this;
  

        var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

        if (!indexedDB) {
            return;
        }

        var open = indexedDB.open(db, 2);

        open.onupgradeneeded = function() {
            ...
        };

        open.onerror = function(event) {
            ...
        };

        open.onsuccess = function(event) {
            debugger;
            console.log("onsuccess")
            ...
        }


    }
}

if(!Indexeddb) {
var Indexeddb = new IndexedDb();
}

export default Indexeddb;
```

Проблема в том, что open.onsuccess не отрабатывает. Если запустить код из консоли то всё отрабатывает

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;
    var open = indexedDB.open(db, 2);
    debugger;
    open.onsuccess = function (event) {
        debugger;
        console.log("onsuccess");
        self.db = event.target.result;
    };
```

В чём может быть проблема такого поведения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что я удалял БД. После удаления БД приходится выключать вкладку в хроме. И только после этого можно опять создать бд и onsuccess будет опять отрабатывать. Версию после удаления бд можно не менять.